# (JS/JQuery) Changing default value/placeholder of custom dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, dropdown

So, here's the HTML for a custom dropdown that doesn't use a select tag. The placeholder/default value for the dropdown is "Acura", which is the first element in the list (ul). I'm trying to see if I can change the placeholder/default value for the dropdown (to say, BMW for example) without changing the order of the list of the dropdown (the makes are in alphabetical order).

```
 <span id="builder-make-selection" class="pick">
  <span class="label">Make:</span>
 <div class="custom-dd-wrapper builder-makes" tabIndex="1">
<div class="custom_dd_select">
    <span>
  <a>Acura</a></span>
</div>
<div class="custom_dd_options">
    <ul class="custom_dropdown">
        <li data-make="Acura">Acura</li>
        <li data-make="Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</li>
        <li data-make="Audi">Audi</li>
        <li data-make="BMW">BMW</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript that's creating the dropdown:

```
 (function(h, a) {
    function k() {
        var b = a(this).parents("div.custom_dd_wrapper"),
            f = b.attr("id"),
            e = a(b).find(".custom_dd_select a"),
            l = a(this).data(),
            d = e.text().trim(),
            g = a(this).text().trim();
        "makes-options" == f && (a(b).addClass("active"), e.parent("span").attr("style", a(this).attr("style")));
        e.text(g);
        for (var m in l) {
            if(m=='make'){
                 e.parent("span").data(m,l[m]);
            }                
        }
        d != g && a(this).closest(".custom_dd_wrapper").trigger("change")
    }

    function g() {
        var b = a(this).closest(".custom_dd_wrapper");
        a(b).find("ul").hide();
        a(b).find(".custom_dd_select").removeClass("click");
        a(b).find(".custom_dd_options").removeClass("show")
    }
    h.CustomDropdownView = function() {
        var b = this;
        this.vc = !1;
        a(".cs").on("click", ".trans-disabled", function(a) {
            a.stopPropagation()
        });
        a(".cs").on("click", ".custom_dd_wrapper, .popup .custom_dd_wrapper", function() {
            b.vc = !0;
            var f = a(this).closest(".custom_dd_wrapper");
            a(f).find("ul").toggle();
            a(f).find(".custom_dd_select").toggleClass("click");
            a(f).find(".custom_dd_options").toggleClass("show")
        });
        a(".cs").on("click", ".custom_dd_options .custom_dropdown > li:not(.trans-disabled)",
            k);
        if (0 > window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") && null == navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) a(".cs").on("blur", ".custom_dd_wrapper, .popup .custom_dd_wrapper", function() {
            a(this).find(".custom_dd_options ul").is(":visible") && g.call(this)
        });
        else a(".cs").on("click", function() {
            if (b.vc) b.vc = !1;
            else {
                var f = a(".custom_dropdown").filter(":visible");
                0 < f.length && f.each(g);
            }
        });
        a(".cs").on("click", ".disable", g)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
<div class="custom_dd_select">
    <span>
  <a>Acura</a></span>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="custom_dd_select">
        <span>
      <a>BMW</a></span>
</div>
```

That will work

Comment: I know, but the HTML is being rendered from the JavaScript, so for changes to reflect on the HTML, the JavaScript must be modified

Comment: then you can write it with a function on document ready that the default will be BMW