# (jQuery) Trying to write a function on document ready to change placeholder for custom dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, in a nutshell, I have this custom dropdown (which doesn't use a select element) for my web application. As you can see in the very brief HTML snippet below, the default value/placeholder for the custom dropdown is "Acura".

```
<span id="builder-make-selection" class="pick">
  <div class="custom_dd_select builder_makes" tabindex="1">
    <div class="custom_dd_select">
      <span>
        <a>Acura</a>
      </span>
```

I'm trying to change the default placeholder for the custom dropdown from "Acura" to "Toyota".

All the HTML for the dropdown is being rendered through the JavaScript, so for the changes to be reflected on the HTML, I have to edit the JavaScript.

So, I'm trying to write a function on document ready that will set the default placeholder to "Toyota". Since I'm terrible with jQuery, I'm not able to get this to work. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(#builder-make-selection .custom_dd_select builder_makes a).text("Toyota");
});
```

Comment: How many sets of `span` in `html`? Where are the closing `div`s?

Comment: more details on this question are available here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490969/js-jquery-changing-default-value-placeholder-of-custom-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(#builder-make-selection .custom_dd_select.builder_makes a).text("Toyota");
});
```

Don't give space between custom_dd_select and builder_makes

Refer this

[How can I select an element with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Try with one class name .In a first div you have two class name `custom_dd_select builder_makes` .If applied with javascript use any one not both

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#builder-make-selection .custom_dd_select a").text("Toyota");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="builder-make-selection" class="pick">
    <div class="custom_dd_select builder_makes" tabindex="1">
    <div class="custom_dd_select">
    <span>
    <a>Acura</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
     </span>
```

Comment: I just tried this and for some reason it's still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

No need to search based on multiple `class`. First find the outer element `builder-make-selection` and then find inner element by respective class `builder_makes`

```
<span id="builder-make-selection" class="pick">
    <div class="custom_dd_select builder_makes" tabindex="1">
      <div class="custom_dd_select">
        <span>
          <a>Acura</a>
       </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</span>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#builder-make-selection .builder_makes a").text("Toyota");
});
```